# loop through options including hidden options

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a select with multiple options. Some of the options are hidden. I want to loop through the options even the hidden ones,

```
$("select option").each(function() { ...
```

to get the options, but i don't get the hidden options, So what can be the way out!

Comment: How do you hide your option elements? Are you using `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: how well are your options hidden? If you have actually removed them, it's no surprise they are nowhere to be found.

Comment: My options are not removed they are just hidden with jquery! like .hide().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to worry about the hidden options while iterating.  You can do it as usual like below and it will include the hidden options.

```
$("select > option").each(function() {
    alert(this.text);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option hidden value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>    
</select>
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ha8Fa/3/)